# Can you have multiple world borders?

Tags: minecraft-commands

I was wondering... I just played an adventure map called limited, and there were multiple world borders to close you in the level. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Barrier blocks?

Comment: Flagging question as unclear because it does not specify which edition is being played.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible in Vanilla Minecraft. You probably played on a modded server, but even there I don't know how it would work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping, even though its impossible

Comment: Please consider pressing the tick if you think this answer solved your question. ^^